# Problems with Codeigniter's Native Session Class

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, codeigniter

so I switched my application over to the Native Session Class is codeigniter due to some problems with IE and sessions. However now, this session class seems to be logging people out very quickly. I have gone over all the code and can't seem to find the problem. Here's the native session class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/wiki/Native_session/

Also all my config vars are the default setting. I am wondering if this is Native Session's fault or my own. I do use a bool var in another script that is used to determined whether the user is logged in. Just thought I'd throw this out there.

BTW, Codeigniter 1.7.3, PHP 5

Comment: A detail blog:http://goo.gl/EeUgk2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was "just use a database". I ended up just using CI's ability to use a database for session data. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html See the section titled "Saving Session Data to a Database"

Comment: oh I also never figured out why *only* IE would do this with regular sessions. Oh well I guess.

Comment: Sorry Tyler, which regexp? I've get lost. Could you explain this a little bit?

Comment: haha not *regular expressions*, **regular session**, as in the default Session engine CI comes with.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniters Sessions are not related to PHP's Sessions. They refresh every (I think) 5 minutes without losing the association to the user. This is a security feature to prevent session-stealing. To have a session longer available, you need to customize the timeouts in the config.

```
$config['sess_expiration']        = 7200;
$config['sess_time_to_update']    = $config['sess_expiration'];
```

Now the time before CI updates it's session is the same as the regular session expiration.

Answer (score 0):

As Dr Colossos says, it's ok to rewrite

`$config['sess_expiration']        = 7200;`

but the 'time to update' should be keep to a lower value. This parameter sets the frequency of the session id regeneration, used to avoid session-stealing, which no means session expiration.

The only problem I remember about IE and CI sessions is that CI uses an undescore for the name of the coockie session and that is somethong that doesn't like to IE, so if you change the name in the sessions config file the problem dissapears.

Comment: as I've said all the variables are set to the default, the session expiration included. the sessions are not lasting more than 5 minutes, usually less.

Comment: You rebumped the question! Great, probably I have new answers ;) It appears the IE doen't kills the cookie that identifies the session, mo matter what you do. It happens sometimes, and only with IE. Not sure how storing session data could affect (and solve) the problem, but a partial fix to IE problem is to use a different cookie based on something that can guessed but changing frecuently, like date.

Comment: Interesting. Is this an IE security thing? And why doesn't this problem occur more frequently?